# Is there a tool to decrypt all SSL/SSH traffic originating from this computer?

Tags: linux, ssh, ssl, tcpdump

I expect the program to scan memory of all local processes (or debug them, or provide crypto libraries with hook like in LD_PRELOAD) and use keys to decrypt traffic, making it analysable with Wireshark and other tools (at least `tcpdump -A`).

Are there tools that collects keys from running processes and decrypts SSL/SSH? Like "see though all local encryption".

The target goal is to see everything flowing to/from my computer, including in encrypted form. I don't like "mysterious" unattended network activity and not being able to know *what* this process is sending them (and too lazy to deal with each case individually).

Comment: Yes, but they are only available in your local office of the Камітэт дзяржаўнай бяспекі, КДБ. ;-)

Comment: Also, the NSA we hear has cracked SSL - you might ask them about this. Seriously, though - ***why would you want to do this***? Do you not trust some of your software? Equally important, do you have legal permission to do this (if done on somebody else's machine)?

Comment: Primarily to view what is being transferred by various programs without manual extraction of things and "Follow SSL stream" per each program - to make it simple.

Comment: Basically I don't like when there are spurious network transfers from/to my computer and I don't know what is it (due to encryption). I want to have simple way to observe what is flowing to/from my computer.

Comment: Encrypted packets will be from secure sessions; they don't just happen out of the blue. You have a VPN running or something? Are you visiting your bank's website?

Comment: Encrypted packets can originate from various programs (also many programs use SSH to start things remotely). When I'm visiting bank's website I can use things like HttpFox (i.e. application-specific)

Comment: Wireshark can decrypt the packages itself. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18456934/how-to-view-encrypted-application-data-in-wireshark): "How to view Encrypted Application Data in Wireshark"

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ssldump](http://www.rtfm.com/ssldump/). It's similar in functionality to tcpdump, but with appropriate privs and keys, you'll can monitor traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I believe encryption keys are not static and they change during the course of a session. So would be almost impossible to achieve this.

Comment: Why? Everything is on my computer (including that encryption keys). The program may even LD_PRELOAD into crypto libraries to subscribe for keys.

Comment: Was thinking off the shelf packet capturing tool, e.g., Wireshark.  LD_PRELOAD would require writing custom libraries.